# Native crash in Activity after starting/stopping a service

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-service

Had a very sporadic native crash that was very difficult to reproduce (the stack trace in no way indicates it would be related to an unrelated service being started/stopped). Eventually managed to narrow it down and have made a very small reproduction class:

```
package com.example.nativecrash

import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class TestService : Service() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val recreate = Runnable { recreate() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_NoActionBar)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        handler.postDelayed(recreate, 500)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        startService(Intent(this, TestService::class.java))
        handler.postDelayed({ stopService(Intent(this, TestService::class.java)) }, 400)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(recreate)
        super.onPause()
    }
}
```

Running that activity on an Android 11 device will reproduce the crash. I found it to occur much more frequently hit running on the emulator (reliably less than a minute until it occurs) than on an actual device but it still happens on both.

Stack trace:

```
2020-09-25 19:33:29.086 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2020-09-25 19:33:29.086 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_64/generic_x86_64_arm64:10/RPP4.200409.015/6455311:user/release-keys'
2020-09-25 19:33:29.086 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2020-09-25 19:33:29.086 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86_64'
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2020-09-25 19:33:29+0930
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: pid: 21124, tid: 21124, name: ple.nativecrash  >>> com.example.nativecrash <<<
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10150
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:     rax 0000000000000000  rbx 0000000000000006  rcx 0000000000000000  rdx 000000000000003f
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:     r8  0000000000000041  r9  00007f589b5cc2f9  r10 00007fff3fb96f50  r11 00007f5adc3a3f88
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:     r12 00007fff3fb96eb0  r13 00007f589b5ccdd0  r14 00007f589b5cc2f0  r15 00007f589b5cc2f0
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:     rdi 00007f588b5ee52f  rsi 00007f588b5ee52f
2020-09-25 19:33:29.087 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:     rbp 0000000000000020  rsp 00007fff3fb96e60  rip 00007f5ae0484926
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 0000000000044926  /system/lib64/libandroidfw.so (android::Theme::SetTo(android::Theme const&)+758) (BuildId: e8c40d5379694fa117849c5f0fba7014)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 00000000001333ca  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeThemeCopy(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, long, long, long)+106) (BuildId: bbfd6cd225dce70beef86960dce8af22)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 00000000002179f5  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+245) (BuildId: 7fc56639bfc361a01712408a01b6fb02a496391e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 0000000000179116  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+806) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 000000000020cb75  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+277) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 00000000003ac005  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+357) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00000000003a1af6  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+934) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 00000000007969a8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStaticRange+520) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 0000000000163519  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static_range+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 000000000036fcb8  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.AssetManager.setThemeTo+28)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 0000000000793a29  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+1513) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 0000000000163399  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_range+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 0000000000376aa4  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl.setTo+28)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 000000000037651c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.Resources$Theme.setTo+8)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 000000000010f00a  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~jA9NSsNmX861v49XTIGS0w==/com.example.nativecrash-f6ZiVgHuiz_wbVwr_-D2zw==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme+62)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 0000000000396c1f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13178773210012645589)+351) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 000000000039fb68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 00000000003a06a9  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1209) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #22 pc 0000000000791fc6  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+710) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #23 pc 0000000000163199  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #24 pc 000000000010ee7e  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~jA9NSsNmX861v49XTIGS0w==/com.example.nativecrash-f6ZiVgHuiz_wbVwr_-D2zw==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme+26)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #25 pc 0000000000396c1f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13178773210012645589)+351) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #26 pc 000000000039fb68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #27 pc 00000000003a06a9  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1209) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #28 pc 000000000078f1c8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1048) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #29 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #30 pc 00000000001fa612  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1256000) (android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme+46)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #31 pc 0000000000792364  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1636) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #32 pc 0000000000163199  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #33 pc 00000000001fa688  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1256000) (android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme+12)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #34 pc 00000000007905d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+2932) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #35 pc 0000000000163119  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_super+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #36 pc 00000000001ab3e4  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Activity.setTheme)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #37 pc 00000000007905d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+2932) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #38 pc 0000000000163119  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_super+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #39 pc 00000000001019d8  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~jA9NSsNmX861v49XTIGS0w==/com.example.nativecrash-f6ZiVgHuiz_wbVwr_-D2zw==/base.apk] (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #40 pc 0000000000396c1f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13178773210012645589)+351) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #41 pc 000000000039fb68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #42 pc 00000000003a06a9  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1209) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #43 pc 000000000078f1c8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1048) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #44 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #45 pc 0000000000199268  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity+740)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #46 pc 0000000000792364  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1636) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #47 pc 0000000000163199  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #48 pc 0000000000198ef2  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity+94)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #49 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #50 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #51 pc 00000000001a08c2  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner+154)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #52 pc 00000000007962fb  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirectRange+1307) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #53 pc 0000000000163499  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct_range+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.217 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #54 pc 00000000001a078c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity+408)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #55 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #56 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #57 pc 000000000028ab14  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute+28)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #58 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #59 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #60 pc 000000000028e9ca  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks+154)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #61 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #62 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #63 pc 000000000028e906  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute+146)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #64 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #65 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #66 pc 00000000001c103a  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction+14)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #67 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #68 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #69 pc 00000000001a096c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally+144)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #70 pc 0000000000396c1f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13178773210012645589)+351) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #71 pc 000000000039fb68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #72 pc 00000000003a06a9  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1209) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #73 pc 0000000000791fc6  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+710) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #74 pc 0000000000163199  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #75 pc 000000000019bc00  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #76 pc 0000000000396c1f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13178773210012645589)+351) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #77 pc 000000000039fb68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #78 pc 00000000003a06a9  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1209) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #79 pc 0000000000792b38  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+696) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #80 pc 0000000000163219  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #81 pc 0000000000198212  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+66)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #82 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #83 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #84 pc 000000000036acbe  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x927000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+38)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #85 pc 000000000078f594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2020) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #86 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #87 pc 0000000000391a5e  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x927000) (android.os.Looper.loop+482)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #88 pc 0000000000792ee7  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1639) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #89 pc 0000000000163219  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #90 pc 00000000001a1f3e  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main+202)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #91 pc 0000000000396c1f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13178773210012645589)+351) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #92 pc 000000000077a9c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1072) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #93 pc 000000000018434c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+140) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #94 pc 0000000000179116  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+806) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #95 pc 000000000020cb75  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+277) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #96 pc 000000000062febe  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+5678) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #97 pc 000000000058df18  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+56) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #98 pc 000000000009afae  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/x86_64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+222) (BuildId: 0e283f9cac599f57d802a9843d949820fe1a2807)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #99 pc 0000000000178db4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+756) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #100 pc 000000000020cb56  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+246) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #101 pc 00000000003ac005  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+357) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #102 pc 00000000003a06c1  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1233) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #103 pc 000000000078f1c8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1048) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #104 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #105 pc 000000000044cf4a  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1256000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #106 pc 0000000000396c1f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13178773210012645589)+351) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #107 pc 000000000077a9c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1072) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #108 pc 000000000018434c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+140) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #109 pc 000000000095b7f7  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2039) (BuildId: 7fc56639bfc361a01712408a01b6fb02a496391e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #110 pc 0000000000179116  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+806) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #111 pc 000000000020cb75  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+277) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #112 pc 000000000062d5b7  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, __va_list_tag*)+487) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #113 pc 00000000004e2c69  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, __va_list_tag*)+665) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #114 pc 000000000041a390  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, __va_list_tag*, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+2864) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #115 pc 00000000004090ae  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, __va_list_tag*)+30) (BuildId: ac7d906af99fd99289c2ce2a1072cf3e)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #116 pc 00000000000afe68  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+168) (BuildId: bbfd6cd225dce70beef86960dce8af22)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #117 pc 00000000000b8401  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+881) (BuildId: bbfd6cd225dce70beef86960dce8af22)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #118 pc 0000000000004190  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1648) (BuildId: d6b2621fa9c788320535274f35331797)
2020-09-25 19:33:29.218 21156-21156/? A/DEBUG:       #119 pc 0000000000050965  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+117) (BuildId: 0cb1ee2e4692086bd16b0cdb7620eb97)
```

Use case is I have an overlay service that runs while the app is foregrounded, and also an option for the user to change theme (which results in `Activity.recreate()` being called). The crash seems to be some sort of race condition with the service start/stop and the activity recreate but I don't see why that should matter.

So I guess my question is twofold:

1: What does starting/stopping a service have to do with an activity eventually crashing deep in native code trying to set the theme.

2: What can possibly be done to avoid this.

Comment: What's the relevance of [tag:c++] in the context of your problem?

Comment: This seems more a issue that needs posting on the Android bug tracker, did you already file a case there?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ since the crash is deep in C++ code (even though its platform and not my code) I thought it somewhat relevant.

Comment: @Fullslack.dev I haven't yet but if I can't find a good answer/solution that will be my next port of call.

Comment: I get this every now and then with my app on a Pixel 4a5G with Android 11.  wish google would fix it.

Comment: By any chance did you find a solution? I am really struggling with something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293193/a-libc-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-segv-maperr-fault-addr-0x740078008d